# Why closed form of this recurrence relation is T(n)=7n-4?

Tags: algorithm

I'm studying the book [Algorithm Design and Applications](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Algorithm+Design+and+Applications-p-9781118335918), and there is a part I couldn't understand:

> ### 1.1.4 Analyzing Recursive Algorithms
>
> [...]
> we can characterize the running time, (), of the **recursiveMax** algorithm as
>
> ```
> () =   3            if  = 1
>        ⎨ ( − 1) + 7 otherwise
> ```
>
> [...] Ideally, we would like to characterize as recurrence equation like that above in ***closed form***, where no references to the function  appear on the righthand side. For the **recursiveMax** algorithm, it isn't too hard to see that a closed form would be () = 7( − 1) + 3 = 7 − 4.

It said:

> it isn't too hard to see that a closed form would be () = 7( − 1) + 3 = 7 − 4.

However, I have no idea how this result came out. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from the earlier observation that:

```
() =   3            if  = 1
       ⎨ ( − 1) + 7 otherwise
```

For larger , the second (inductive) case can be expanded repeatedly:

```
() = ( − 1) + 7
     = (( − 2) + 7) + 7
     = ((( − 3) + 7) + 7) + 7
     = ...
     = ( − ) + 7
```

When  =  − 1, we arrive at the base case

```
     = (1) + 7( − 1)
     = 7( − 1) + 3
     = 7 − 4
```